# Images in jQuery Script won't load in Slider

Tags: jquery

I have copied the files and code from this page [Basic-slider.com](http://basic-slider.com/)

But when I preview it the images appear broken and below the body.  I'm not sure why as I've given it a higher z-index and arranged it to be on top.  Also when I change it so the images are in a table/list they show up but then I don't have a slider.
This is how I've coded it so far:

Head:

```
<title>Tech and Innovation</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="bjqs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="bjqs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
        'height' : 320,
        'width' : 620,
        'responsive' : true
    });
});
</script>

</head>
```

Body HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    </div>
    <div align="center">
<div id="body" style="width: 960px; left: 0px; top: 0px">

<div id="my-slideshow" style="height: 500px; z-index: 3;">
    <ul class="bjqs">
        <li><img alt="" height="310" src="img/banner01.jpg" width="620" /></li>
    <li><img alt="" height="310" src="img/banner03.jpg" width="620" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer" style="height: 178px">

</div>

</div>


</body>
```

CSS:

```
ul.bjqs{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}

li.bjqs-slide{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

ul.bjqs-controls{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:9999;
}

ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a{position:absolute;}

ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-next a{right:0;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a{left:0;}

ol.bjqs-markers{list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;}

ol.bjqs-markers.h-centered {text-align: center;}
ol.bjqs-markers li {display:inline;}

ol.bjqs-markers li a {display:inline-block;}

p.bjqs-caption {
    display:block;
    width:96%;
    margin:0;
    padding:2%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong but I'm sure it's something simple as I'm self-taught and finding things the hard way at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead.

```
$(function() {
     $('#my-slideshow').bjqs({
        'height' : 320,
        'width' : 620,
        'responsive' : true
    });
});
```

Comment: I've put that code in but my images still seem to be broken/hidden.  I really dont get why as theres nothing to suggest they should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery version is

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

and css path is correct